# How to get String[] A - String[] B i.e. all elements which are in A but not in B ,In java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String [] allEmps ; String array Of All emps;

```
String [] allEmps = StringUtil.convertCommaStringToArray(listOfEmpsCommaSep, ",");
```

I have another String [] EmpsWithCompensationDefined

```
String [] listOfEmpsWithCompDefined =  DBUtility.selectFieldAndReturnAsStringArray(QueryToGetEmpsWhomCompIsDefined, con);
```

Now I want to get employees whom compensation is not defined i.e An entry which is in A but not in B.

Solution : I can iterate over both the array and get the difference. But this would be O(n^2) complex. Is there any other way with less asymptotic complexity?

Edit:

```
ArrayList listOfFilteredEmps = new ArrayList();
                    for(int j =0;j<allEmps.length;j++){
                        boolean isMatched = false;
                        for(int i=0;i<listOfEmpsWithCompDefined.length;i++){
                            if(allEmps[j]==listOfEmpsWithCompDefined[i]){
                                isMatched = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(!isMatched){
                            if(listOfFilteredEmps!=null && listOfFilteredEmps.size()==0){
                                listOfFilteredEmps.add(allEmps[j]);
                            }else{
                                listOfFilteredEmps.add(","+allEmps[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Share your code what have you done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
String [] allEmps={"A","B","C","D"};
String [] listOfEmpsWithCompDefined={"A","D","E"};
Set<String> mySet1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(allEmps)); // convert to set
Set<String> mySet2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(listOfEmpsWithCompDefined));
mySet1.removeAll(mySet2);// elements which are in A but not in B 
String[] df = mySet1.toArray(new String[mySet1.size()]);// difference
```